# propositional logic - arguments -> conclusion question

Tags: logic

I don't really understand how to decide whether arguments are correct or not. For example, I have a question with 4 arguments: E,F,G,H, say, and then this leads to for premises, say: W,X,Y, where the latter is some combination of the variables E,F,G,H.

Now I know that for every situation all the premises are true, the conclusion is true, and as I can't think of a short way of doing this, I drew up a truth table.The conclusion is that F is True.

From the truth table I end up with: (see below link) https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVroz.png

I think the arguments are correct as for all premises, WXY, the conclusion F is true as well. i.e.F is true in 4 cases for which all the premises are true. However since some other variables are true, I was wondering whether this nullifies the argument that F is true? i.e. does F have to be strictly True, and others all have to be false for the conclusion to hold?

Also does anyone know of any good websites/videos that help explain the concept better. I want to get to a place where I can do this without truth tables! We were taught in class to find a case where all premises are true and then try to find a case where the conclusion is false, but I can't get my head around this concept!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: 4 arguments ? Usually we have **one** argument with many (at least one) *premises* and one *conclusion*.

Comment: But YES; and argument is *valid* iff: when all the premises are TRUE also the conclusion is TRUE. So, to use truth table to check validity of arguments, you have to "highlight" all the rows where all the premises have T and check if in them also the conclsuion has T.

Comment: Example of argument: $P \lor Q, \lnot Q \vdash P$. You have to build a t-t  with prop letters $P,Q$ and thus $2^2=4$ rows and three further columns: one for each premises and one for the conclusion. Then check that in the (only) row where both $P \lor Q$ and $\lnot Q$ have T, also $P$ has.